# Error message when trying to run OneDrive.exe

Tags: windows-10, office365, onedrive

I'm running Windows 10 and I have Office 365. It's my personal PC, not using Active Directory.

When I'm trying to use OneDrive and when I open it, I get this error:

> We cannot synchronize your documents anymore

I tried `sfc /scannow`, `ccleaner` and others tricks. No change at all.

I'm thinking it's due to Office 365 connected to my OneDrive PRO.
Anyone have any information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I read the microsoft forum and many people face the same issue.One of the solution I came across is:

> Hey everyone. I just found what might be the solution in another discussion thread on this same forum. It is suggested to Uninstall the new OneDrive for Business. You should see it in your Programs and Features control panel.

Here is the link for further info

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/forum/odfeatures/microsoft-onedrive-notification-on-desktop-we-cant/0e20fca5-832c-4928-9438-71484fba3255